# Express server communicating with React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I am trying to redirect to my React App after authenticating the login.
But its not working, don't know why.

React App at port **3000**

Server at port **3001**

I am routing to server on login submit -> server authenticate using passport -> it should redirect to React App route '/secured'. Instead it is showing `GET http://localhost:3001/secured 404 (Not Found)`
It is routing to the server address. How to resolve this?

Authentication is working fine. I have checked it all using postman.

**EXPRESS SERVER**

```
//middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000', //location of frontend app (react app here)
    credentials: true,
}))

app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}))

app.use(cookieParser('secret'))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
require('./models/passport-config')(passport)

// routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Home route')
})

app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
        if (err) { return next(err) }
        if (!user) { return res.redirect('/') }

        req.logIn(user, (err) => {
            if (err) { return next(err) }
            return res.redirect('/secured')
        })

    })(req, res, next)
})

app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
})
app.get('/user', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user)
})

// server init
app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('serving at http://localhost:3001...')
})
```

"REACT APP - App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Register from './components/Register';
import Login from './components/Login';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/secured" component={Register} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**REACT APP - Login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import "./login.css"
import axios from 'axios'

class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            username: null,
            password: null,
        }
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        })
    }


    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        axios({
            method: "post",
            data: this.state,
            withCredentials: true,
            url: 'http://localhost:3001/login'
        })
        // .then(this.getData())

    }

    getData = () => {
        axios({
            method: "get",
            data: this.state,
            withCredentials: true,
            url: 'http://localhost:3001/user'
        }).then(res => {
            this.setState({
                username: res.data['0'].username,
                email: res.data['0'].email,
                password: null
            });
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <div>
                    <form id='login' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <div>
                            <h3>Login</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                            <div >
                               
                                <input onChange={this.handleChange} id="icon_prefix" type="text" name='username' />
                                <label htmlFor="icon_prefix">Username</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div >
                              
                                <input onChange={this.handleChange} id="icon_prefix" type="password"  name='password' />
                                <label htmlFor="icon_prefix2">Password</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                            <div >
                                <input type='submit' />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div>
                        Already a member? <a href="/secured">Register here</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }

}

export default Login
```

Comment: You should redirect to react app not nodejs app `http://localhost:3000/secured`, `/secured` will redirct to nodejs app, pass full path.

Comment: you should also consider how this entire project will be hosted in a production environment. Sure, in development, your react frontend runs it's own server on a separate port, but when you build the project, it's just going to compile to some static assets which you will need to host... you could then be using your backend express app to serve those static assets, in which case, the port will be the same / you will only have the one server handling the requests

Comment: Its giving error about cors policy voilation - `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/secured' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3001/login') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`@SujeetAgrahari

Comment: @andersryanc Yes. I tried it but its was hell of confusing. So I am going for separate setup build first.

Comment: Under your current setup, you’d need to set `origin: *` in your node config, to allow all origins. Either that, or don’t redirect the way you’re doing now. The reason is, when a request gets redirected across origins — in this case, redirected from `http://localhost:3001` back to `http://localhost:3000` — the browser throws out the initial origin (`http://localhost:3000`) and replaces it with a null value that won’t match any actual real origin value. So then the only thing that would work is if the Access-Control-Allow-Origin value is `*` — to allow all origins. Either that, or don’t redirect

Comment: I think that @SujeetAgrahari is on the right path though... really, the better way is probably not to redirect from the server, but instead handle success or error case in the browser based on the response your server sends back to the frontend.

Comment: Thanks @sideshowbarker. But `origin:*` is showing syntactically wrong.

Comment: I am also thinking to do that as last resort @andersryanc.

Comment: it's really the way it should be done. you backend isn't rendering your frontend and shouldn't handle redirect logic. your backend code should just be an API you interact with to send/receive data. you could eventually have them joined together in the production environment, but you could also choose to run them on totally separate domains like www.example.com and api.example.com

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `handleSubmit` function in your `<Login />` component, you should add the `.then()` callback, check the response for error/success and then either show an error to the user in the UI or use [React Router History](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history) to `push` or `replace` the current route.

Another option would maybe be to store a state variable in your `<Login />` component, like `this.state.isAuthenticated` which you could then check in your `render()` method and choose to return a [React Router Redirect](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect) like:

```js
render() {
  if (this.state.isAuthenticated) {
    return <Redirect to="/somewhere/else" />
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```